# How can I call a ptx function from CUDA C?

Tags: assembly, cuda, inline-assembly

I am trying to find a way to call a ptx function (.func) from CUDA C.
Say I had a ptx function like this:

```
.func (.reg .s32 %res) inc_ptr ( .reg .s32 %ptr, .reg .s32 %inc )
{
    add.s32 %res, %ptr, %inc;
    ret;
}
```

I know I can call it from ptx like so:

```
call (%d), inc_ptr, (%s, %d);
```

But I have no idea how to call it from CUDA C.
I know I can inline ptx assembly with asm(), but I haven't found a way to inline a function.
Hope someone can help!

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, I think it might not be possible. The problem is that CUDA C doesn't come with a linker for device code. So everything that runs from one kernel must be in the same .cu file. I hope I'm wrong, because, IMO, NVIDIA did a poor job with the syntax for inlined PTX.

Comment: @RogerDahl Yeah that's what I was fearing as well. However it looks like there could be coming a device code linker in CUDA 5 (http://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/cuda/files/CUDADownloads/GPU_Library_Object_Linking.pdf). I haven't found out how to do it in the CUDA 5 Preview though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using the separate compilation facilities introduced with CUDA 5.0. I don't believe there is a way to do this in "whole" program compilation mode or in toolkit versions prior to CUDA 5.0 or in PTX revisions prior to 3.1.

It is probably easiest to illustrate how to do this with a worked example. Let's start with a simple PTX function for incrementing pointers, similar to your example:

```
.version 3.1
.target sm_30
.address_size 32
.visible .func inc_ptr(.param .b32 ptr, .param .b32 inc)
{
    .reg .s32   %r<6>;
    ld.param.u32 %r1, [ptr];
    ld.param.u32 %r2, [inc];
    ld.u32 %r3, [%r1];
    ld.u32 %r4, [%r3];
    add.s32 %r5, %r4, %r2;
    st.u32  [%r3], %r5;
    ret;
}
```

This can be compiled to a relocatable device object using `ptxas` and then packed into a fatbinary container file. The latter step seems to be critical. The default `ptxas` output is only a relocatable `elf` object, there is no fatbinary container produced. It seems that the device code linkage phase that nvcc runs (at least in CUDA 5) is expecting all device code is present in fatbinary containers. The linkage will fail otherwise. The result looks like this:

```
$ ptxas -arch=sm_30 -c -o inc_ptr.gpu.o inc_ptr.ptx
$ fatbinary -arch=sm_30 -create inc_ptr.fatbin -elf inc_ptr.gpu.o 
$ cuobjdump -sass inc_ptr.fatbin 

Fatbin elf code:
================
arch = sm_30
code version = [1,6]
producer = <unknown>
host = mac
compile_size = 32bit

    code for sm_30
        Function : inc_ptr
    /*0008*/     /*0x0040dc8580000000*/     LD R3, [R4];
    /*0010*/     /*0x00301c8580000000*/     LD R0, [R3];
    /*0018*/     /*0x14001c0348000000*/     IADD R0, R0, R5;
    /*0020*/     /*0x00301c8590000000*/     ST [R3], R0;
    /*0028*/     /*0x00001de790000000*/     RET;
    /*0030*/     /*0x00001de440000000*/     NOP CC.T;
    /*0038*/     /*0x00001de440000000*/     NOP CC.T;
    /*0040*/     /*0xe0001de74003ffff*/     BRA 0x40;
    /*0048*/     /*0x00001de440000000*/     NOP CC.T;
    /*0050*/     /*0x00001de440000000*/     NOP CC.T;
    /*0058*/     /*0x00001de440000000*/     NOP CC.T;
    /*0060*/     /*0x00001de440000000*/     NOP CC.T;
    /*0068*/     /*0x00001de440000000*/     NOP CC.T;
    /*0070*/     /*0x00001de440000000*/     NOP CC.T;
    /*0078*/     /*0x00001de440000000*/     NOP CC.T;
        ........................
```

You can see that the fatbinary contains the microcode from the assembled PTX. With the device function fatbin prepared, you can do something like this in CUDA C code:

```
extern "C" __device__ void inc_ptr(int* &ptr, const int inc);

__global__
void memsetkernel(int *inout, const int val, const int N)
{
    int stride = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
    int *p = inout;
    inc_ptr(p, threadIdx.x + blockDim.x*blockIdx.x);

    for(; p < inout+N; inc_ptr(p, stride)) *p = val;
}  


int main(void)
{
    const int n=10;
    int *p;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&p, sizeof(int)*size_t(n));
    memsetkernel<<<1,32>>>(p, 5, n);

    return 0;
}
```

In separate compilation mode, the device code toolchain will respect the `extern` declaration and (as long as you get symbol mangling under control), the device function fatbinary can be linked with other device and host code to produce a final object:

```
$ nvcc -arch=sm_30 -Xptxas="-v" -dlink -o memset.out inc_ptr.fatbin memset_kernel.cu 

ptxas info    : 0 bytes gmem
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function '_Z12memsetkernelPiii' for 'sm_30'
ptxas info    : Function properties for _Z12memsetkernelPiii
    8 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 20 registers, 332 bytes cmem[0]

$ cuobjdump -sass memset.out 

Fatbin elf code:
================
arch = sm_30
code version = [1,6]
producer = <unknown>
host = mac
compile_size = 32bit
identifier = inc_ptr.fatbin memset_kernel.cu 

    code for sm_30
        Function : _Z12memsetkernelPiii
    /*0008*/     /*0x10005de428004001*/     MOV R1, c [0x0] [0x44];
    /*0010*/     /*0x20105d034800c000*/     IADD R1, R1, -0x8;
    /*0018*/     /*0x00019de428004005*/     MOV R6, c [0x0] [0x140];
    /*0020*/     /*0x10101c034800c000*/     IADD R0, R1, 0x4;
    /*0028*/     /*0x8400dc042c000000*/     S2R R3, SR_Tid_X;
    /*0030*/     /*0x90041c0348004000*/     IADD R16, R0, c [0x0] [0x24];
    /*0038*/     /*0x94001c042c000000*/     S2R R0, SR_CTAid_X;
    /*0048*/     /*0xd0009de428004000*/     MOV R2, c [0x0] [0x34];
    /*0050*/     /*0x91045d0348004000*/     IADD R17, R16, -c [0x0] [0x24];
    /*0058*/     /*0x40011de428000000*/     MOV R4, R16;
    /*0060*/     /*0xa0015ca320064000*/     IMAD R5, R0, c [0x0] [0x28], R3;
    /*0068*/     /*0x01119c85c8000000*/     STL [R17], R6;
    /*0070*/     /*0xa0209ca350004000*/     IMUL R2, R2, c [0x0] [0x28];
    /*0078*/     /*0x0001000710000000*/     JCAL 0x0;
    /*0088*/     /*0x0110dc85c0000000*/     LDL R3, [R17];
    /*0090*/     /*0x20001de428004005*/     MOV R0, c [0x0] [0x148];
    /*0098*/     /*0x00049c4340004005*/     ISCADD R18, R0, c [0x0] [0x140], 0x2;
    /*00a0*/     /*0x4831dc031b0e0000*/     ISETP.GE.U32.AND P0, pt, R3, R18, pt;
    /*00a8*/     /*0x000001e780000000*/     @P0 EXIT;
    /*00b0*/     /*0x1004dde428004005*/     MOV R19, c [0x0] [0x144];
    /*00b8*/     /*0x0034dc8590000000*/     ST [R3], R19;
    /*00c8*/     /*0x40011de428000000*/     MOV R4, R16;
    /*00d0*/     /*0x08015de428000000*/     MOV R5, R2;
    /*00d8*/     /*0x0001000710000000*/     JCAL 0x0;
    /*00e0*/     /*0x0110dc85c0000000*/     LDL R3, [R17];
    /*00e8*/     /*0x4831dc03188e0000*/     ISETP.LT.U32.AND P0, pt, R3, R18, pt;
    /*00f0*/     /*0x000001e74003ffff*/     @P0 BRA 0xb8;
    /*00f8*/     /*0x00001de780000000*/     EXIT;
    /*0100*/     /*0xe0001de74003ffff*/     BRA 0x100;
    /*0108*/     /*0x00001de440000000*/     NOP CC.T;
    /*0110*/     /*0x00001de440000000*/     NOP CC.T;
    /*0118*/     /*0x00001de440000000*/     NOP CC.T;
    /*0120*/     /*0x00001de440000000*/     NOP CC.T;
    /*0128*/     /*0x00001de440000000*/     NOP CC.T;
    /*0130*/     /*0x00001de440000000*/     NOP CC.T;
    /*0138*/     /*0x00001de440000000*/     NOP CC.T;
        .....................................


        Function : inc_ptr
    /*0008*/     /*0x0040dc8580000000*/     LD R3, [R4];
    /*0010*/     /*0x00301c8580000000*/     LD R0, [R3];
    /*0018*/     /*0x14001c0348000000*/     IADD R0, R0, R5;
    /*0020*/     /*0x00301c8590000000*/     ST [R3], R0;
    /*0028*/     /*0x00001de790000000*/     RET;
    /*0030*/     /*0x00001de440000000*/     NOP CC.T;
    /*0038*/     /*0x00001de440000000*/     NOP CC.T;
    /*0040*/     /*0xe0001de74003ffff*/     BRA 0x40;
    /*0048*/     /*0x00001de440000000*/     NOP CC.T;
    /*0050*/     /*0x00001de440000000*/     NOP CC.T;
    /*0058*/     /*0x00001de440000000*/     NOP CC.T;
    /*0060*/     /*0x00001de440000000*/     NOP CC.T;
    /*0068*/     /*0x00001de440000000*/     NOP CC.T;
    /*0070*/     /*0x00001de440000000*/     NOP CC.T;
    /*0078*/     /*0x00001de440000000*/     NOP CC.T;
        ........................
```

There might be other tricks which can be played with the toolchain to achieve this, but this approach certainly works.

Comment: Added an answer to get this off the unanswered question list if someone would be so kind as to upvote it and/or accept it.

Comment: OK one question.  How do I create an executable that incorporates your device-linked object (memset.out)?

Answer (score -1):

As far as i know, CUDA C supports asm, there is a doc which locate in doc directory after cuda tool kit installed.

Comment: Yes CUDA C supports asm, and as I wrote I know I can inline assembly code in CUDA C, but I don't know how to inline a ptx assembly function (.func).